# command traefik error: flag needs an argument: -kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes

When kubernetes(v.1.15.2) start Traefik(2.x) pods,the error output is:

```
2020/01/29 07:40:52 command traefik error: flag needs an argument: -kubernetes
```

this is my daemon set yaml:

```
{
  "kind": "DaemonSet",
  "apiVersion": "extensions/v1beta1",
  "metadata": {
    "name": "traefik-ingress-lb",
    "namespace": "kube-system",
    "selfLink": "/apis/extensions/v1beta1/namespaces/kube-system/daemonsets/traefik-ingress-lb",
    "uid": "6aee6973-681d-4a8e-814b-2d279ed00ffd",
    "resourceVersion": "12736249",
    "generation": 3,
    "creationTimestamp": "2020-01-28T14:49:22Z",
    "labels": {
      "k8s-app": "traefik-ingress-lb"
    }
  },
  "spec": {
    "selector": {
      "matchLabels": {
        "k8s-app": "traefik-ingress-lb",
        "name": "traefik-ingress-lb"
      }
    },
    "template": {
      "metadata": {
        "creationTimestamp": null,
        "labels": {
          "k8s-app": "traefik-ingress-lb",
          "name": "traefik-ingress-lb"
        }
      },
      "spec": {
        "containers": [
          {
            "name": "traefik-ingress-lb",
            "image": "traefik",
            "args": [
              "--web",
              "--web.address=:8580",
              "--kubernetes"
            ],
            "ports": [
              {
                "name": "http",
                "hostPort": 80,
                "containerPort": 80,
                "protocol": "TCP"
              },
              {
                "name": "admin",
                "hostPort": 8580,
                "containerPort": 8580,
                "protocol": "TCP"
              }
            ],
            "resources": {
              "limits": {
                "cpu": "200m",
                "memory": "30Mi"
              },
              "requests": {
                "cpu": "100m",
                "memory": "20Mi"
              }
            },
            "terminationMessagePath": "/dev/termination-log",
            "terminationMessagePolicy": "File",
            "imagePullPolicy": "Always"
          }
        ],
        "restartPolicy": "Always",
        "terminationGracePeriodSeconds": 60,
        "dnsPolicy": "ClusterFirst",
        "nodeSelector": {
          "edgenode": "true"
        },
        "serviceAccountName": "ingress",
        "serviceAccount": "ingress",
        "hostNetwork": true,
        "securityContext": {},
        "schedulerName": "default-scheduler"
      }
    },
    "updateStrategy": {
      "type": "OnDelete"
    },
    "templateGeneration": 3,
    "revisionHistoryLimit": 10
  },
  "status": {
    "currentNumberScheduled": 3,
    "numberMisscheduled": 0,
    "desiredNumberScheduled": 3,
    "numberReady": 0,
    "observedGeneration": 3,
    "updatedNumberScheduled": 3,
    "numberUnavailable": 3
  }
}
```

and this is my ingress-rbac.yaml:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ServiceAccount
metadata:
  name: ingress
  namespace: kube-system

---

kind: ClusterRoleBinding
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1beta1
metadata:
  name: ingress
subjects:
  - kind: ServiceAccount
    name: ingress
    namespace: kube-system
roleRef:
  kind: ClusterRole
  name: cluster-admin
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
```

this is ingress.yaml:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: traefik-ingress
  namespace: default
spec:
  rules:
  - host: traefik.nginx.io
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        backend:
          serviceName: my-nginx
          servicePort: 80
  - host: traefik.frontend.io
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        backend:
          serviceName: frontend
          servicePort: 80
```

the pods shows: `Back-off restarting failed container` . [image]what should I do to fix this?

Comment: I don't see a `--kubernetes` option listed at all in [the Traefik docs](https://docs.traefik.io/reference/static-configuration/cli/).

Comment: Based on [traefik v2.0 official documentation](https://docs.traefik.io/reference/static-configuration/cli/) there is no such flag as `--kubernetes`. This flag can be found only in v1.x.

Comment: maybe the Traefik updated and the deploy guidline is too old and now I change other way to deploy.

Comment: Did you manage to solve the issue? If so, can you post the answer for community and mark it as accepted?